# EXCEL Function for conditional search and paste of certain value in target column needed

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm currently working on sorting a big excel sheet with projects, working hours and employees and make it into an overview per employee on worksheet2. The projects, employees are sorted horizontally in rows and the months organized vertically, with showing how the working hours per month in the column of each employee. So it is something like this I have to work with, to give a fictional example and transform it into an overview per employee:

[See for Excel Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/psFeB.png)

What I need to do is to filter the rows for employees, copy the project they are involved in into my new worksheet as a column and get the matching working hours per month per project. All needs to be done automatically, if new employees or projects are added, that it updates automatically. Key is to get an overview per employee. The difficulty is, that the employees in the 1. worksheet are mentioned several times, that I have to track them, get the column they are mentioned and copy certain values in that column.

I tried working with `IF`, `MATCH`, `INDEX` and what I have so far is 
`=INDEX(Worksheet1!S2:AY11;10;MATCH(Employee1; Worksheet1!S11:AY11; 0))`

but that is only half of the solution and only tells me, where the first employee is located in the large horizontal list and copy the name into the cell.

Maybe someone of you has an idea how to match a value that exists multiple times and copy certain cells (working hours, project) from that column of the employee. THANK YOU!

Comment: You probably don't have the FILTER function I'm guessing.

Comment: it needs to be automatically, so if the employees change or some new are added, the list will update projects, working hours, etc. automatically...

Comment: The FILTER function (dynamic array, available in Excel 365), is dynamic - but I'm guessing you don't have it. If not, VBA is probably easier here.

Comment: 1) How are months organized? 2) On a column on the left? 3) Single value that "covers" multiple rows? 4) Can there be more than one person per month per project? 5) Why are there those empty cells under project 1? 6) Are you open to use Visual Basic or you need a formula based solution only?

Comment: I may be misunderstanding the objective, but it sounds like you could skip filtering and copying the names by using a 'SUMIFS()' or 'COUNTIFS()' function. For example, sum the values in this row if the first cell next to it is "Mark" and the second cell next to it is "project 1".

Comment: @EvilBlueMonkey 1) the months are organized  in column1 (Oct, Nov, Dec,...) on the left.
 4) yes, there can be more than one person per month per project 5) The empty cells also exist in the original worksheet, probably to add more names to the project if needed. (actually the empty cells also have hours per month, but no name; so I can ignore them for my second worksheet). 6) I am open to any solution, but I havn't used VBA successfully yet.

Comment: Very well. Then i might came up with something with VBA. Can you please share a broader example of the sheet? Something like 3 months with multiple names and project. Of course i don't need the original information, just the structure filled with made-up information.

Comment: @EvilBlueMonkey Thank you very much, I updated the post and inserted a broad example of the necessary information in the sheet

Comment: Woundabar. Working on it. Question: those dates are written down as dates? They are not strings, right?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()

    'Declarations.
    Dim WksReport As Worksheet
    Dim WksData As Worksheet
    Dim RngDataFirstCell As Range
    Dim RngReportFirstCell As Range
    Dim RngRange01 As Range
    Dim RngTarget As Range
    Dim IntCounter01 As Integer
    Dim StrTotalLabel As String

    'Setting variables.
    Set WksReport = Sheets(Me.Name)                 'put here the sheet where the report will be contained (no need to edit if it remain a worksheet_activate sub)
    Set WksData = Sheets("Foglio7")                 'put here the sheet where the data will be contained
    Set RngDataFirstCell = WksData.Range("A2")      'put here the first top left cell of the data table (according to your screenshot it's A2)
    Set RngReportFirstCell = WksReport.Range("B2")  'put here the first top left cell of the report table
    StrTotalLabel = "Gesamt"                        'put here the label used for columns with totals

    'Asking permission to update the report. If denied, the sub is terminated.
    If MsgBox("Update the report?", vbYesNo, "Report update") = 7 Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'Checking for pre-existing report.
    If RngReportFirstCell.Value <> "" Then

        'Setting RngTarget.
        Set RngTarget = WksReport.Range(RngReportFirstCell, WksReport.Cells(RngReportFirstCell.Offset(0, 1).End(xlDown).Row, RngReportFirstCell.Offset(0, 3).column))

        'Clearing RngTarget.
        RngTarget.ClearContents
        RngTarget.ClearFormats

    End If

    'Typing in the report's label.
    RngReportFirstCell.Value = "Person"                         'Person
    RngReportFirstCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "Project"           'Project
    RngReportFirstCell.Offset(0, 2).Value = "Monat"             'Month
    RngReportFirstCell.Offset(0, 3).Value = "Arbeitsstunde"     'Working hour

    'Setting RngRange01 to cover the data without any row/column tag.
    Set RngTarget = RngDataFirstCell.EntireRow.Find("", RngDataFirstCell, xlValues, xlWhole, xlByColumns, xlNext, False, , False).Offset(2, -1)
    Set RngRange01 = RngDataFirstCell.EntireColumn.Find("", RngDataFirstCell.Offset(2, 0), xlValues, xlWhole, xlByRows, xlNext, False, , False).Offset(-1, 1)
    Set RngRange01 = WksData.Range(RngTarget, RngRange01)

    'Covering each cell in RngRange01.
    IntCounter01 = 1
    For Each RngTarget In RngRange01

        'Checking if the column is not labeled for totals.
        If WksData.Cells(RngDataFirstCell.Row + 1, RngTarget.column) <> StrTotalLabel Then

            'Report the person.
            RngReportFirstCell.Offset(IntCounter01, 0).Value = WksData.Cells(RngDataFirstCell.Row + 1, RngTarget.column)
            'Report the project.
            RngReportFirstCell.Offset(IntCounter01, 1).Value = WksData.Cells(RngDataFirstCell.Row, RngTarget.column)
            'Report the month.
            RngReportFirstCell.Offset(IntCounter01, 2).Value = WksData.Cells(RngTarget.Row, RngDataFirstCell.column)
            'Report the working hour.
            RngReportFirstCell.Offset(IntCounter01, 3).Value = RngTarget.Value

            'Setting IntCounter01 for the next row.
            IntCounter01 = IntCounter01 + 1
        End If

    Next

End Sub
```

It is designed as a private Worksheet_Activate subroutine, therefore it must be placed in the report sheet module. It basically cover every cell of your data, as long as there are no gaps between months or between projects. Then it reports the cell value on a row with the relative person, project and month. It already ignores your totals (Gesamt). This way you should be easily apply a pivot table on it. Tell me if it works and if you need any clarifications as well as edits/improvements.